# schema_translate_map for SQLALchemy AsyncSession

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I need to change PostgreSQL schema in SQLAlchemy `AsyncSession` session.

For sync Session we have `session.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {None: schema}})`

For async I found a way to do it: `MyModel.__table__.schema = "MySchema`, but it will change the model in runtime which is really bad for async code.

Is there something like `schema_translate_map` for `AsyncSession`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same exact problem and the way I fix it is doing like this:

```
from asyncio import current_task
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, async_scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


async def main()
    db_connstring = "postgresql+asyncpg://scott:tiger@localhost/test"
    engine = create_async_engine(db_connstring, pool_pre_ping=True)
    session = async_scoped_session(
sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession),
scopefunc=current_task)

    schema = "my_schema"
    connection = await session.connection()
    await connection.execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: schema})
    ...
```

Comment: thx for the answer. I originally solved the issue by deepcopieng the model class and changing it like that `model_copy.__table__.schema = self.schema`. Looked bad.